# Elastic Search Complex Sorting

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have an ES document which has a category_id field. Every category_id has some priority for which I have mappings in DataBase. Now, I want to apply a search which can be applied on priority. The search is being used to show the suggestion in UI on keypress and shows only 10 - 15 results. I want to show the higher priority items first. Also, to keep the priority as a newer field in the document, does not make more sense as it will be updated time to time and that will require updation across all the documents matching that category.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html

Comment: I could not see the solution at link you pointed out. Could you please describe it more.

Comment: You will be sorting documents by their score. When you query data provide `custom_score` clasuse with autogenerated `script` field - something like `_score * ((doc['category_id'].value == 1) ? MY_PRIORITY_NUMBER1 : MY_PRIORITY_NUMBER2)` where MY_PRIORITY_NUMBERs are values from your DB table. When you have more than 2 categories just chain ternary operators or use `if` or `switch` or whatever you want - MVEL (which is used by default) is a fully functional expression language

Comment: More examples here http://jontai.me/blog/2013/01/advanced-scoring-in-elasticsearch/